# Laravel 5. Many-to-many relationsip. Build query

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, many-to-many

Tables:

```
categories
--id

materials
--id

category_material
--id
--category_id
--material_id
```

Models:

```
class Material extends Model {
    public function categories(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
    }
}

class Category extends Model {
    public function materials(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Material');
    }
}
```

I need all materials from "category_id = 1"

Trying:

```
$category_id = '1';
$materials = Material::with('categories')->where('category_id', $category_id)->get();
```

**Unknown column 'materials.category_id'**

```
$category_id = '1';
$materials = Material::with(['categories',function($query) use ($category_id){
    $query->where('category_id', $category_id);
}])->get();
```

**ErrorException in Builder.php line 792:
explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given**

Help me, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array passed to `with` should be in `relation_name => closure` format

```
$category_id = '1';
$materials = Material::whereHas('categories', function($query) use ($category_id){
    $query->where('category_id', $category_id);
})->get();
```

Comment: thank you, but now: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'category_id' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: add the pivot table name to where query and try. Assuming it is `category_material` use it like this in the where query `category_material.category_id`.

Comment: Not erorrs, but i get all materials (I need only from "category_id = 1")

Comment: It's work..
I looked logs. Why get so hard query?
Can I make simple "SELECT m.* FROM `materials` m LEFT JOIN `category_material` cm ON m.id = cm.material_id WHERE cm.category_id = 1" by the Eloquent ORM??